# Admob ads displaying over buttons on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, admob, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I was testing an app for compatibility with Jelly Bean when I noticed that a Admob ads (Admob SDK 6.1.0) were being displayed on top of the buttons in the app. The layout I'm using is:

```
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spinner"
            android:maxWidth="350sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/line"/>
        <View android:id="@+id/ad" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/line"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/generate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ad"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="@string/generate"/>
```

What happens is that when the ad loads, it displays on top of the button. In previous versions of Android (ICS and older), the ad would load and the button would be pushed down to accommodate the ad. Does anyone know how I can restore this functionality on Jelly Bean? Thanks!

Comment: paste snapshot how it looks meand differenece in view

Comment: @Khan A screenshot really won't help here. All it is is an ad. There's a button underneath it, but you wouldn't know from a screenshot. The XML code above is much more helpful.

Comment: i have used same sdk and check admob my admob is at align bottom same result in 2.2 emulator or jelly bean emulator my xml view contain header,listview and admob either add full xml code and let me check it

Comment: @Khan Thanks for your help. I posted my workaround as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem is to implement the AdListener interface to manually set the top margin of the button when an ad is loaded. This moves the button down and prevents it from being covered up by the ad.

```
@Override
public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {      
    // Move the generate button down by the height of the ad on load
    MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams)generateBtn.getLayoutParams();
    params.topMargin = AdSize.BANNER.getHeightInPixels(this);
    generateBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

And since this problem only happens on Jelly Bean, only set the AdListener if running on Jelly Bean

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    ad.setAdListener(this);
```

Comment: fyi, might be more useful to do the `if` logic inside onReceiveAd instead of deciding to add the listener. You'll have to do this later if you ever want to do anything else inside this callback.

Comment: This is true, and I might have to do that in the future. In this case, though, I was thinking why even bother adding a listener that does nothing to non-Jelly Bean devices? Seems a little less efficient.